# Package naming convention

Tags: java, naming-conventions, package, naming

The typical case is that a package is prepended with a url, to prevent conflicts.

E.g. com.example.helloworld

What do you do with a multi-part TLD, e.g. co.nz?

1. co.nz.example.helloworld, or
2. nz.co.example.helloworld

Thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The convention is to write the domain name backwards, so it should be

```
nz.co.example.helloworld
```

This is explained in the [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html).